# Spring Boot - How to trigger a task after request to an endpoint has been completed

Tags: spring-boot

I have somewhat unusual requirement for one of my POST requests.  It has to do following:

1. controller receives request and calls a service (which then calls JpaRepository) to persist data in a database
2. return response (2xx, 4xx, 5xx) based on result from #1 above
3. **then immediately call another service to send the same data it persisted to another API**

#1 and #2 above are clear and working just fine

But #3 is unusual because at that point, the request is already completed and response was already sent to the client in #2 step.  (Basically, the client considers its request success if it has been persisted to the database, regardless if it was forwarded to the other API for further processing).

This means that #3 needs to be somehow triggered after the fact or some other way.

I believe, but not sure, C# would use something like Tasks for this and have task completion block to take over #3 (or maybe something else).

But I have no idea what would be appropriate for such a scenario in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2):

As @Salmane Tamo suggested, you can just do a asynchronous call to other API before returning the response. It can just be as simple as having `@Async` on a public void method & `@EnableAsync`. Ref: [Spring Async](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async). As calling service don't care about this API call, you can error log in cases of any error responses from your API call.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use Events in Spring Boot. [This](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-application-events-explained/) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) are good articles you can checkout.

Events in Spring are synchronous by default, but you may consider asynchronous events if you do not necessarily have to wait before sending back a response for your requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).